# Fpdf goes to header Location without generating Pdf.

Tags: php, html, pdf, post

The page automatically redirects to entry.php without generating the pdf. I want it to generate the pdf and then redirect. When the header(Location: entry.php); is removed, it generates Pdf. Is there any other way to achieve it?

```
include('connection.php');  
ob_start ();  
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');  


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  
{
    //collect form data
    $name = $_POST['fname'];  
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];  
    $gender=$_POST['dropdown1'];  
    $age=$_POST['age'];  
    $qualification=$_POST['qualification'];  
    $fees=$_POST['fee'];  
    $discount=$_POST['discount'];  
    $tobepaid=$_POST['tobepaid'];  
    $paystatus=$_POST['dropdown2'];  


    $query = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE email = '$email'";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));  

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['registered'] = "Record Already exists.";  
    mysqli_close($conn);  
    header('Location: entry.php');  
    exit();  


}  
    else  


$sql = "INSERT INTO details(FirstName, LastName, Email, Sex, Age, Qualification, Fees, Discount, Tobepaid, Paystatus)
 VALUES ('$name', '$lname', '$email', '$gender', '$age', '$qualification', '$fees', '$discount', '$tobepaid', '$paystatus')";  

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  


    if( !mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result ))  
{
$_SESSION['Msg']= "Submitted Successfully";  


            class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()  
{


    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(60,10,'Convert HTML TO PDF',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer  
function Footer()  
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom  
    $this->SetY(-15);  
    // Arial italic 8  
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);  
    // Page number  
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');  
}  
}  

// Instanciation of inherited class  
$pdf = new PDF();  
$pdf->AliasNbPages();  
$pdf->AddPage();  
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);  

$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Name : '.$_POST["lname"],0,1);  
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Email : '.$_POST["email"],0,1);  
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Mobile : '.$_POST["fname"],0,1);  
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Comment : '.$_POST["age"],0,1);  

    $pdfname=$_SESSION['UserID'];  


$pdf->Output('Filename.pdf','D');  

    header("Location: entry.php");  
}  

else{
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Invalid Details";
    header("Location: entry.php");

}
```

Comment: Do you need to output the pdf and write it to the disk before you move to entry.php.  At first glance it looks like it is just outputting it to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

**D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.**

so your arpprach should be to use

**F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).**